# How can i group list-items using a data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can i  group a List Items based data attribute data-group? I am trying to avoid duplicate in my list based on the following conditions.

My Conditions are:

1. If Same `PartyName` and `SubPartyName` appears multiple times I want to merge them
2. If same  `PartyName` but different `subPartyName` group by `PartyName`.

Below is my code to create a list:

```
    <ul id="list">
     @foreach (var item in Info){
      <li data-group="@item.PartyName" data-expanded="true"> @item.PartyName
         <ul>
             <li data-group="@item.SubPartyName" data-expanded="true">@item.subPartyName</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     }</ul>
```

My current list looks like as shown below:

> Party A
>
> - SubParty A
>
> Party A
>
> - SubParty B
>
> Party A
>
> - SubParty B
>
> Party A
>       Party B
>       Party C

I Would like to see my list as:

---

> Party A
>
> - SubParty A
> - SubParty B
>
> Party B
>       Party C

Comment: You have to edit your `Model` relation query, and include `GROUP BY` clause. Or show us how you query this objects.

Comment: show your model relation

Comment: Show your model relation, or DB map

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
 public class InfoClass
{
    public string PartyName { get; set; }
    public string SubPartyName { get; set; }
}

public class NewInfoClass
{
    public string PartyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubPartyName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<InfoClass> infos = new List<InfoClass>();
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party A", SubPartyName = "SubParty A" });
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party A", SubPartyName = "SubParty B" });
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party A", SubPartyName = "SubParty B" });
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party A" });
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party B" });
        infos.Add(new InfoClass() { PartyName = "Party C" });

        var results = from p in infos
                      group p.SubPartyName by p.PartyName into g
                      select new { PartyName = g.Key, SubPartyNames = g.ToList().Distinct() };

        List<NewInfoClass> newList = new List<NewInfoClass>();

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            newList.Add(new NewInfoClass()
            {
                PartyName = item.PartyName,
            });
            newList[count].SubPartyName = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item2 in item.SubPartyNames)
            {
                if (item2 != null)
                {
                    newList[count].SubPartyName.Add(item2);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return View(newList);
    }
```

View

```
@model List<DemoApplication.Models.NewInfoClass>
<ul id="list">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li data-group="@item.PartyName" data-expanded="true">
        @item.PartyName
        @foreach (var item2 in item.SubPartyName)
        {
            <ul>
                <li data-group="@item2" data-expanded="true">@item2</li>
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
```

Comment: is there anyways to group by this `  var sprp = rParties.Concat(subparties.ToList());`?